# Contentbyquery web part is not filtering on content type

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have 5 document libraries on my site collection.
3 of them have content types enabled, and all content types begins with the same id.

2 of those are the standard sharepoint document librraries named Documents and Site Collection Documents.

My CQWP is returning all of them, but it should return only the ones on the first 3 document libraries.

```
 #region Last updated documents
                                ContentByQueryWebPart cqwp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
                                cqwp.BaseType = "1";
                                cqwp.ContentTypeBeginsWithId = "0x0101008E49C3D400044AB3A2F1DD14073E74F6001D06D12572244BE3A11AAEE3ED60F576";
                                cqwp.WebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                                cqwp.Title = "Last Updated Documents";                                
                                string query = @"<OrderBy> "+
                                                    "<FieldRef Name='Modified'  Ascending='FALSE'/> "+
                                                "</OrderBy>";
                                cqwp.QueryOverride = query;
                                cqwp.ItemLimit = 10;
                                cqwp.ListsOverride =  "<Lists ServerTemplate='101'/>";
                                cqwp.WebsOverride = "<Webs Recursive='False' />";


                                cqwp.MainXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl");
                                cqwp.HeaderXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl");
                                cqwp.ItemXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl");

                                cqwp.CommonViewFields= "Name, Text; Modified, DateTime";                           

                                mgrPageManager.AddWebPart(cqwp, "Footer", 0);
                                mgrPageManager.SaveChanges(cqwp);
                            #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the begins with apparently doesnt work byitself

in the query override I had to add CAML and the BeginsWith then it works